# decimal suffix in C# prints unexpected value

Tags: c#, decimal, string-formatting, currency-formatting

The below initialization...

`Account account1 = new Account("Jane Green", 50.00m);`

...should, when running the relevant test class I wrote, render a console line...

`Jane Green's balance: €50,00`

...according to the book and the test class I copied from it (the book says $50,00 but because of the chosen syntax, see further, the console **should** write it in Euros).

Instead, it gives me a line that reads:

`Jane Green's balance: 50,00 ?`

The same happens when adding money to the account via the Deposit account method, and even though it should give me confirmation in Euros because of the line...

`Console.WriteLine($"{account1.Name}'s balance: {account1.Balance:C}");`

It stubbornly prints...

`Jane Green's balance: 75,00 ?`

I have searched for solutions by adjusting my PC's regional and keyboard settings as I suspect this to be part of the problem but to no avail (I live in Belgium, so Azerty kb(comma spaced) and Euro's for currency)

Can anyone tell me how to make it write the correct output?

Comment: You need to tell it which culture you want it to use, have a look at the documentation for the `ToString(IFormatProvider)` function.

Comment: The console can't print `€`. Every "special" character is replaced by `?` if you try to write it to the console.

Comment: EDIT: As BACON said this was partially a duplicate: aldjusting the font in my console did the trick together with the Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8 line; However, I still need to modify my keyboard entry as the program will not allow entries of decimals containing a comma instead of a point. Still, many thanks to everyone who replied!!

Comment: Just to note, a quick way to establish that this is a console problem and not a string formatting problem is to take string formatting out of the equation and see what `Console.WriteLine("€");` produces in the console.  Alternatively, take the console out of the equation and see what `System.IO.File.AppendAllText("output.txt", $"{account1.Name}'s balance: {account1.Balance:C}");` produces in the output file.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings), the formatted string output will be `50,00 €` (rather than `€50,00` as you expected). However, the console is not displaying the Euro character correctly - it is being replaced with `?`.

You can fix this with `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`

Comment: This works, but only if I use a .(point) instead of the 'culturally correct' comma that my keyboard is set to, so not a watertight solution...still, thanks for the fast response!

Comment: @Nomana Forgonzzo  You can use an input string with the local decimal separator, then convert it to decimal before printing it: `decimal Balance = decimal.Parse([StringInput], NumberStyles.Currency, culture);`  where `culture` is the Culture setting you see in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `Console.OutputEncoding` to `UTF8` addresses the first part of your problem:

```
using System.Text;
// ...
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Now you can use these alternatives for the Euro symbol (Belgium):

**Option 1**: Change the default format. This affects all your code.

```
using System.Globalization;
// ...
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-be");
Console.WriteLine($"Jane Green's balance: {50.00m:C}");
```

**Option 2**: Format your number to string before using it with C#'s string interpolation.

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-be");
Console.WriteLine($"Jane Green's balance: {50.00m.ToString("C2", culture)}");
```

**Option 3**: Use your string as FormattableString, and a predefined culture:

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-be");
Console.WriteLine(((FormattableString)$"Jane Green's balance: {50.00m:C}").ToString(culture));
```

All of the options ABOVE give you this:

> Jane Green's balance: 50,00 €

**WHICH IS CLEARLY -NOT- WHAT YOU'VE EXPECTED**

If you need this:

> Jane Green's balance: € 50,00

Then you should first define a custom format provider:

```
NumberFormatInfo numberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo()
{
    CurrencySymbol = "€",
    CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2,
    CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",",
    CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".",
    CurrencyGroupSizes = new int[] { 3 }, // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencygroupsizes(v=vs.110).aspx
    CurrencyNegativePattern = 12, // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern(v=vs.110).aspx
    CurrencyPositivePattern = 2, // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern(v=vs.110).aspx
};
```

**Option 4**: Use FormattableString with your custom format.

```
Console.WriteLine(
    ((FormattableString)$"Jane Green's balance: {50.00m:C}").ToString(numberFormat) );
```

**Option 5**: Create a convenient helper class for formatting the string before printing it to the console.

```
public static class Log
{
    static Log() { Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; }

    public static IFormatProvider CustomFormat =
        new NumberFormatInfo() { ... };

    public static void WriteLine(FormattableString str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str.ToString(CustomFormat ?? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
    }
}

//...

Log.WriteLine($"Jane Green's balance: {50.00m:C}");
Log.CustomFormat = ...
```

See also the list of [Language & Country Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx).

Comment: I get the message that CultureInfo does not exist in the existing context... thanks for the reply though. It made perfect sense...

Comment: @Nomana Forgonzzo   You are missing `using System.Globalization;`